# How to create Repository under folder?

Tags: github

I have created a folder, named "My Other Repos". Can I create several repositories under that folder? (so, not in my profile root).

Comment: Yes. `cd My\ Other\ Repos; mkdir NewRepo; cd NewRepo; git init`

Comment: Did you try that? It should work out of the box. In your shoes, I would avoid paths with spaces inside though.

Comment: @Gavin I assume that the root folder is not already a Git repository?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP is asking about creating git repos "under `My Other Repos`", so I'm assuming it's not a repo already.